# AS3/Flash: Array convertion (two questions)

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, sorting, duplicates

1) I have this array:

```
var n:Array = ["JAMES", "JANE", "JAMEL"...];
```

and I need to transfor to this:

```
var nt:Array = [{label:"JAMES"}, {label:"JANE"}, {label:"JAMEL"}...];
```

2) Is it possible to sort and remove duplicated names in:

```
var n:Array = [{label:"JAMES"}, {label:"JANE"}, {label:"JAMEL"}, {label:"JANE"},...];
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var initialArray: Array = ["JAMES", "JANE", "JAMEL", "JANE", "JAMEL"];
var resultingArray: Array = [];
//Sorting array
initialArray.sort();
//Removing duplicates
var i: int = 0;
while (i < initialArray.length) {
    while (i < initialArray.length + 1 && initialArray[i] == initialArray[i + 1]) {
        initialArray.splice(i, 1);
    }
    i++;
}
//Converting
for each(var elem: Object in initialArray) {
    var currentObject: Object = new Object();
    currentObject.label = elem;
    resultingArray.push(currentObject);
}
```

You can then work with the resultingArray

You may also want to use original for or while loop, it will possibly increase the speed of this piece of code.

Comment: Thanks KumoKairo. I did use the convertion and worked as a charm. Anyway, I must do a general code cleaning. Cheers.